# Number of ways to cover 3xN board

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given a 3xN board. Find the number of ways to cover it using 2x2 or 3x1 or 1x3 tiles.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Answer (score 1):

I read your question carefully, and the answer is zero. The question you wrote may not have been the question that you meant to ask.

I see you changed it...

It’s a simple dynamic programming problem. Assume that the board is 3 pieces high and N pieces wide, and assume that you always add another piece in the leftmost position. Then at any time you have filled k complete columns, with some pieces in the next columns. Take a sheet of paper to draw all the possibilities, and in many cases you have only one choice for the next piece.